# How to pass custom parameters to parent construct?

Tags: magento2, construct

I have extended `\Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order` to Custom class like below,but not able pass one more parameter(**`$httpClientFactory`**) to this construct level.

How to pass custom parameters(**`$httpClientFactory`**) to parent construct?

```
<?php
class Custom extends \Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory
     */
    protected $layoutFactory;

    /**
     * @param Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Translate\InlineInterface $translateInline
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory $resultLayoutFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory $resultRawFactory
     * @param OrderManagementInterface $orderManagement
     * @param OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory $layoutFactory
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
     */
    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Translate\InlineInterface $translateInline,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory $resultLayoutFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory $resultRawFactory,
        OrderManagementInterface $orderManagement,
        OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory $layoutFactory,
        **\Magento\Framework\HTTP\ZendClientFactory $httpClientFactory**
    ) {
        $this->layoutFactory = $layoutFactory;
        **$this->_httpClientFactory = $httpClientFactory;**
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $coreRegistry,
            $fileFactory,
            $translateInline,
            $resultPageFactory,
            $resultJsonFactory,
            $resultLayoutFactory,
            $resultRawFactory,
            $orderManagement,
            $orderRepository,
            $logger
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to define `_httpClientFactory` before your constructor

Comment: like `protected $_httpClientFactory`

Comment: I have defined also like protected $_httpClientFactory , but it is not working

Comment: what error did you get?

Comment: why do you need this `_httpClientFactory`?

Comment: Not able to create constructor  object  i.e. any type of object  with this extended class \Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order

Comment: what is your goal for this? are you trying to get data from `\Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order`?

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: After extending this class, need to load one more parameter like below,

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager
) {
    $this->_objectManager = $objectmanager;
}

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 1):

I think you are forgetting to add use statement for certain classes like

> Action\Context $context,
>
> OrderManagementInterface $orderManagement,
>
> OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository

etc. Also, I'm not able to see any namespace for your class.
Your file should look like below.

```
<?php

namespace [Vendors]\[Module]\Controller\Adminhtml;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class Custom extends \Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory
     */
    protected $layoutFactory;

    /**
     * @param Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Translate\InlineInterface $translateInline
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory $resultLayoutFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory $resultRawFactory
     * @param OrderManagementInterface $orderManagement
     * @param OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory $layoutFactory
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
     */
    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Translate\InlineInterface $translateInline,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory $resultLayoutFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory $resultRawFactory,
        OrderManagementInterface $orderManagement,
        OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory $layoutFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\HTTP\ZendClientFactory $httpClientFactory
    ) {
        $this->layoutFactory = $layoutFactory;
        $this->_httpClientFactory = $httpClientFactory;
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $coreRegistry,
            $fileFactory,
            $translateInline,
            $resultPageFactory,
            $resultJsonFactory,
            $resultLayoutFactory,
            $resultRawFactory,
            $orderManagement,
            $orderRepository,
            $logger
        );
    }
}
```

Try this. After making changes clear generated folder and flush cache. It may work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
<?php
class Custom extends \Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory
     */
    protected $layoutFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\HTTP\ZendClientFactory 
     */
    protected $_httpClientFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface 
     */
    protected $_objectManager;

    /**
     * Custom constructor.
     * @param Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Translate\InlineInterface $translateInline
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory $resultLayoutFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory $resultRawFactory
     * @param OrderManagementInterface $orderManagement
     * @param OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory $layoutFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\HTTP\ZendClientFactory $httpClientFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager
     */
    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Translate\InlineInterface $translateInline,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory $resultLayoutFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory $resultRawFactory,
        OrderManagementInterface $orderManagement,
        OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory $layoutFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\HTTP\ZendClientFactory $httpClientFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager
    ) {
        $this->layoutFactory = $layoutFactory;
        $this->_httpClientFactory = $httpClientFactory;
        $this->_objectManager = $objectmanager;
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $coreRegistry,
            $fileFactory,
            $translateInline,
            $resultPageFactory,
            $resultJsonFactory,
            $resultLayoutFactory,
            $resultRawFactory,
            $orderManagement,
            $orderRepository,
            $logger
        );
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        //you execute logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: getting error like A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later.

Comment: not able to add/ override constructor properly